# Useful type of clustering method

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, unsupervised-learning

I have a set of points in $R^3$ whose volume is increasing as time goes by.
They tend to be clustered but I don't know how many. Also, the number of clustering might be changing when new points enter. Since the number of points is huge, I don't want to recalculate every time when new points enter.
What type of clustering methods might be useful? I'm only familiar with K-means clustering, but in this case, it is not helpful a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible for your given problem, I would suggest using an online algorithm - i.e. using one example at a time - like [BIRCH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIRCH) or [Sequential K-Means](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall08/cos436/Duda/C/sk_means.htm)